# How to limit my method visibility

Tags: java, methods, access-modifiers

I'm learning about method/class access controlling in Java right now, and I'm having a bit of trouble setting this method to anything besides public. Idealy, I'd like `TestLib` to be invisible to `JavaApplication8`, as in programs can utilize methods in TestLib without seeing the source. Here is what I have right now:

TestLib:

```
package testlib;
import java.awt.Robot;
public class TestLib {
    private static void moveMouse(int x, int y){
        try{
            Robot robot = new Robot();
            robot.mouseMove(x, y);
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Error");
        }
    }
}
```

JavaApplication8:

```
package javaapplication8;

import testlib.TestLib;

public class JavaApplication8 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       TestLib.moveMouse(10, 20);
    }
}
```

I am not allowed to access `TestLib.moveMouse(x, y)` unless I set method to public, which I'm pretty sure is bad practice. How can I get around this?

Thanks!

Comment: do you want to hide source and forbid execution?

Comment: I want to hide the source of TestLib from the end user, I want to distribute it as a library when it's finished.

Comment: then make all methods which are allowed to be called as public and compile your sources into jar file, so users will be able to use, but they don't see sources

Comment: You're completely misunderstanding visibility levels; they have nothing to do with source code.

Comment: Ah I've misunderstood then, my bad! Still good to use the correct visibility levels I guess, better get that down now

Comment: @Lashane I'm already doing that, I didn't know thats what it did though. Thanks!

Comment: public, private, and default have nothing to do with being able to view source code, it has to do with in what scope a method/field can be accessed. What you need is obfuscation of code.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as `visibility levels` there is only `access levels` in java. Visibility is about the programmer (human). You need to compile your code and provide a JAR. This will allow humans to USE the code without seeing the inner details. However, ALL api's will always be visible.

Public, protected, private are access levels. They control the level of which the methods can be USED (not viewed).

Answer (score 0):

What you want is for `moveMouse()` to be only visible in the package scope. That is, methods only in the same package can see the `moveMouse()`. For this to happen, use the `default` modifier rather than `public`. So the method will now look like:

```
default static void moveMouse(int x, int y){
    try{
        Robot robot = new Robot();
        robot.mouseMove(x, y);
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Error");
    }
}
```

Since `moveMouse()` is in `package testlib` it is not visible to `package javaapplication8`.

Comment: What if I get an error saying `default` is not supported in my version of java? Is there a different way to do this? Is using public visibiltiy REALLY that bad? I'm on the fence between having this open source or closed source, so if I go open source would having all methods as public be harmful in any way?

Comment: The "default" modifier doesn't mean put "default" in front of the method. It means *don't put a modifier at all*. Two different things. `default` on methods is only supported for default methods in Java 8's interfaces.

Comment: Hmm ok, so whether I go open source or closed source, its not going to make a difference, but if I set all methods in my library to public, is that a bad thing?

Comment: @Nathan Depends on what methods you have in your library.

Comment: @user3580294 , explain?

Comment: @Nathan What methods you want accessible depends on your public API and how you want your library designed. Generally methods that expose API implementation details shouldn't be publicly visible, as they limit the ability for your library to change. If your library doesn't have any of those methods, then making all your methods `public` wouldn't necessarily be a bad thing.

Answer (score 0):

> Want to hide the source of TestLib from the end user, I want to
>   distribute it as a library when it's finished.

Here, the visibility in the [access modifiers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html) are not related to this.

Although you distribute it via a jar file, the classes can be decompiled and get the source. There are thousands of decompilers. (eg [jd-gui](http://jd.benow.ca/)). So, here you should work with the Java security.(eg : digitally signed jars etc.) To protect the source from the end users.

Here's bonus info for visibility (programatically) taken from the [oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html).

[image]

References :
[Protect jars from visibility - google](https://www.google.lk/search?q=access+modifiers+in+java&oq=access+modif&aqs=chrome.2.69i57j0l3.4764j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=protect%20jar%20file%20from%20decompilation)